# Get all matching records where IDs are joined to a comma separated list

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I have two database table like below:

1. **Form**

   - Id
   - Name
   - Fields(varchar-255)
2. **FormFields**

   - Id
   - Name
   - InputType

Sample data for **Form**

```
Id    Name     Fields
1     Form1    1,2,3
2     Form2    1,2
```

Sample data for **FormFields**

```
Id    Name     InputType
1     FName    TEXT
2     Lname    TEXT
3     Email    TEXT
```

Now I write query as below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM FormFields 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Fields FROM Form WHERE Id = 2)
```

And I get only one record as below:

```
Id    Name     InputType
1     FName    TEXT
```

But I want all the records of **FormFields** table whose **Id** is present in the **Fields** columns of **Form** table. I want result like this:

```
Id    Name     InputType
1     FName    TEXT
2     Lname    TEXT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You cannot use `IN` to search for specific value inside comma delimited "string"**.
You can use [**`FIND_IN_SET`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) for this:

```sql
SELECT FormFields.*
FROM Form
INNER JOIN FormFields ON FIND_IN_SET(FormFields.id, Form.Fields) > 0
WHERE Form.Id = 2
```

Result:

```
+------+-------+-----------+
| Id   | Name  | InputType |
+------+-------+-----------+
|    1 | FName | TEXT      |
|    2 | Lname | TEXT      |
+------+-------+-----------+
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d024/3)

---

Having said that, I would suggest creating a many-many table that joins Forms to Fields. Rough outline of table structure:

- Form (id, name)
- Field (id, name, type)
- FormField (form_id, field_id)

Comment: Who exactly has a problem with this answer and why?

Comment: No idea it's working for me. Might be a little slower on large data sets than IN though depending on his DB.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to redesign your tables.

You have multiple forms, and multiple fields. One field can belong to multiple forms. One form can have multiple fields.
This is a **many-to-many relation**

How to do this properly?
The answer is: using a third table where you join the ID's together.

For example:

```
FormHasFields
FormId | FieldId
1        1
1        2
1        3
2        1
2        2
```

In this case you wouldn't need to column `fields` in your `Form` table.
It will be more performant and easier to manage.

Your query to get all the fields where form id is 2, would be:

```
SELECT * FROM FormFields
JOIN FormHasFields on FormFields.id = FormHasFields.FieldId
JOIN Form on FormHasFields.FormId = Forms.id
WHERE Form.id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, redesign your Forms table to mapping table as follows:

```
FormId FieldId
------ -------
1      1
1      2
1      3
2      1
2      2
```

And then make a query like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM FormFields ff
JOIN Forms f ON ff.id = f.fieldid
WHERE f.form_id = 2;
```

It should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this is what is happening in short:

You have let say two table:
Table Employee
id, locationid, name, status

1, 1, test,1
2, 1, test1,0
3, 2, test2,1
3, 3, test3,1
3, 4, test4,1

Table Users
id,allowedlocationids, username etc

1,[1,2,3],testuser

Now you want to get all records from employee table that are working with location 1 and 2 for logged in user testuser

`` SELECT * FROM employee WHERE `status`=1 AND `locationid` IN (SELECT locationid FROM employee WHERE FIND_IN_SET(locationid,'1,2,3') ) ``

take note 1,2,3 are location the user has permission to see
Then this will be your output:

```
1, 1, test,1
3, 2, test2,1
3, 3, test3,1
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
SELECT * FROM FormFields 
WHERE Formfields.Id IN(SELECT Fields FROM Form)
```

Drop the `WHERE id = 2` from the IN as well.

Comment: then how to identify the fields for particular form ?

Comment: I don't think you understand how `IN` works. Why would I want a `WHERE id = 2` in my `SELECT`? This means it will only look for the value in the row with an ID of 2. This is clearly demonstrated by your similar answer below that shows the wrong result

Answer (score -2):

Isn't it should be like this -

```
SELECT * FROM FormFields 
WHERE Id IN(SELECT Fields FROM Form WHERE Id = 2)
```

Comment: It returns only one row, not 2 or 3.

Comment: It only checks the row with ID 2

Comment: You didnt checked the question , please check again ,  required is only 1 & 2  ,  not 1,2,3, , Queru is like this   -  SELECT * FROM FormFields 
WHERE Id IN(1,2)

Comment: You did not check the output of your query.

Comment: `WHERE Id = 2` means it will only look in Forms where `Forms.Id = 2` which means only a single result is possible.

Comment: @iamgory yes , thats what we need, fields for form Id = 2

Comment: @praveen: I checked, your query returns one row (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d024/2). Look at the question and the expected output again.

Comment: `FormFields table which contains Id from Fields` - so he wants to search for FormFields.Id in Forms.Fields. Your query of `WHERE id = 2` means it will only search `Forms` WHERE Forms.Id = 2. It will ONLY check a single line. So if he looks for FormFields.id = 2, it will only return 1 row when the correct result is 2 rows.